# Twitter View Conversation

Tags: twitter

How do I get the "View Conversation" option to my tweets. I've seen https://twitter.com/DBZNappa and https://twitter.com/#!/StealthMountain/favorites do so with the @reply function, but my tweets only show the "Expand" option.

Comment: Are you replying to the tweets or manually entering @user into the tweets?

Comment: Manually. How do I get my bot to reply to tweets?

Comment: Check the `in_reply_to_status_id` parameter - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update

Comment: @Bibhas - Thanks. I got it fixed now.